# Hooking two batch files together with set values (premature exit?)

Tags: file, batch-file

One problem is that something crashes trying to call createserver.bat at the end of this

```
del %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\serverparams.cmd
wget http://***/serverparams.cmd

call serverparams.cmd

IF name==default (
del %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\serverparams.cmd
call senderror.bat
) ELSE (
randomport -default -defaut -default
timeout /t 1
) 
IF NOT name==default (
sysresourceoutput
timeout /t 5
call sysresources
IF %ram% GTR 1600 (
call %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TerrariaServer\createserver.bat
)
)
```

Though createserver.bat alone runs fine.

Another problem is linking the set values from calling serverparams.cmd.. or setting the serverparams values correctly at all, using the above, though running it through a series of commands in startserver below is a-ok (in the base directory).

```
call setname.cmd
call setvars.cmd

set path=%USERPROFILE%\desktop\TerrariaServer

ECHO set port=%var1% >%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set players=%var2% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set autocreate=%var3% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set worldname=%var4% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set password=%var5% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set motd=%var6% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set lang=%var7% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set priority=%var8% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd
ECHO set name=%name% >>%path%\%name%_set.cmd

call %name%_set.cmd

ECHO maxplayers=%players% >%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO world=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds\%worldname%.wld >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO port=%port% >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO password=%password% >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO motd=%motd% >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO worldpath=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds\ >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO secure=1 >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO lang=%lang% >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO upnp=0 >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO #npcstream=60 >>%path%\%name%_config.txt
ECHO priority=%priority% >>%path%\%name%_config.txt

ECHO IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds\%worldname%" ( >%path%\%name%_start.bat
ECHO TerrariaServer -config %path%\%name%_config.txt >>%path%\%name%_start.bat
ECHO ) ELSE ( >>%name%_start.bat
ECHO TerrariaServer -config %path%\%name%_config.txt -port %port% -players %players% -world "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds\%worldname%.wld" -autocreate %autocreate% -worldname %worldname%.wld >>%path%\%name%_start.bat
ECHO ) >>%path%\%name%_start.bat

call %path%\%name%_start.bat
```

My question is, are there any nuances I'm missing? I think there's a more dynamic way to list a set of incrementing variables, other than manually naming them var01, var02

Also, it puts a space after %worldname%, but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines like this will never execute as there are no %variables% to evaluate, it is comparing static strings which aren't the same.

`IF name==default (`

Lines like this will fail when the user profile contains spaces or & characters.  The solution is to enclose the entire "path\filename" in double quotes:

`del "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\serverparams.cmd"`

Lines like this should be edited to include the redirection at the start of the line.  That solves the spaces at the end of each line.

`ECHO set port=%var1% >%path%\%name%_set.cmd`

Rewrite the lines in this manner and remove the trailing spaces

```
>"%path%\%name%_set.cmd" ECHO set port=%var1%
>>"%path%\%name%_set.cmd" ECHO set players=%var2%
```

Include the double quotes to cater for long pathname\filename elements, and change the %path% name to something else as `PATH` is a system variable and using it will break everything.

Comment: Lines like `IF %ram% GTR 1600 (` will fail within a compound statement if the variable is undefined when the block begins, and will use the starting value of the variable, not any value assigned within the block like in `call sysresources`. See endless solutions here related to `delayed expansion`.

Comment: "IF name==default (" Funny. So the lack of defining %ram% and such caused the failure.